# tr tag from table doesn't start on new line

Tags: html, html-table

Can somebody please explain to me why the second row is not on a new line?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.rotate').css('height', $('.rotate').width());
});
```

```css
td {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 1px black solid;
}

th {
  border: 1px black solid;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

tr {
  text-align: center;
}

.rotate {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-90.0deg);
  transform: rotate(-90.0deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0" align="center">
  <caption>SCARA GEOCRONOLOGICĂ</caption>
  <tr>
    <th rowspan="2">EON</th>
    <th colspan="2" rowspan="2">ERA</th>
    <th colspan="3" rowspan="2">PERIOADA</th>
    <th colspan="2" rowspan="2">Cicluri orogenice</th>
    <th rowspan="2">Mil. ani în urmă</th>
    <th colspan="4" rowspan="2">Viețuitoare tipice</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="13">FANEROZOIC</td>
    <td colspan="2" rowspan="4">CAINOZOIC(NEOZOIC) Cz</td>
    <td colspan="3">Cuaternar Q</td>
    <td colspan="2" rowspan="3">Ciclul alpin</td>
    <td rowspan="15">0,01</td>
    <td colspan="4">Omul primitiv, mamut, ren, bou moscat, rinocer</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

([*fiddle*](https://jsfiddle.net/u506p4xo/))

Comment: Your `rowspan` and `colspan` values seem to have no relation to your table structure.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/vhj3dxp7/1/, use `tbody` and `thead` tags to differentiate between body and head of the table

Comment: @Mr.Alien Ty, it worked.. But why do i need to use it .. Does table doesn't know automaticilly that ? With smaller tables is no problem, but with bigger is other thing..

Answer (score 2):

`rowspan="2"` in the `th` elements (even in *all*  of them) doesn't really make sense. If you remove it, you get a regular table:

```css
table {
border-collapse: collapse;
}
td, th {
border: 1px dotted #aaa;
}
```

```html
<table cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0" align="center">
    <caption>SCARA GEOCRONOLOGICĂ</caption>
    <tr>
        <th>EON</th>
        <th colspan="2">ERA</th>
        <th colspan="3">PERIOADA</th>
        <th colspan="2">Cicluri orogenice</th>
        <th>Mil. ani în urmă</th>
        <th colspan="4">Viețuitoare tipice</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="13">FANEROZOIC</td>
        <td colspan="2" rowspan="4">CAINOZOIC(NEOZOIC) Cz</td>
        <td colspan="3">Cuaternar Q</td>
        <td colspan="2" rowspan="3">Ciclul alpin</td>
        <td rowspan="15">0,01</td>
        <td colspan="4">Omul primitiv, mamut, ren, bou moscat, rinocer</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: My table is bigger than that, that's just the beggining, anyway i fixed my problem with thead and tbody

Comment: @DarksNemeSySs if you not specify thead and tbody browser will automatically put all the rows in tbody ,check by inspecting in developer tools

Answer (score 1):

Use **`thead`** and **`tbody`** tag

```html
<table cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0" align="center">
    <caption>SCARA GEOCRONOLOGICĂ</caption>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th rowspan="2">EON</th>
        <th colspan="2" rowspan="2">ERA</th>
        <th colspan="3" rowspan="2">PERIOADA</th>
        <th colspan="2" rowspan="2">Cicluri orogenice</th>
        <th rowspan="2">Mil. ani în urmă</th>
        <th colspan="4" rowspan="2">Viețuitoare tipice</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="13">FANEROZOIC</td>
        <td colspan="2" rowspan="4">CAINOZOIC(NEOZOIC) Cz</td>
        <td colspan="3">Cuaternar Q</td>
        <td colspan="2" rowspan="3">Ciclul alpin</td>
        <td rowspan="15">0,01</td>
        <td colspan="4">Omul primitiv, mamut, ren, bou moscat, rinocer</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just include row of head part (`<th>`) to the `<thead>` tag and the other part of the row inlude in `<tbody>`. Hope it will help work as you expect.

```css
 td {
        border-collapse: collapse;
        border: 1px black solid;
    }
th {
    border: 1px black solid;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
tr {
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
  
    <table cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0" align="center">
        <caption>SCARA GEOCRONOLOGICĂ</caption>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th rowspan="2">EON</th>
                <th colspan="2" rowspan="2">ERA</th>
                <th colspan="3" rowspan="2">PERIOADA</th>
                <th colspan="2" rowspan="2">Cicluri orogenice</th>
                <th rowspan="2">Mil. ani în urmă</th>
                <th colspan="4" rowspan="2">Viețuitoare tipice</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td rowspan="13">FANEROZOIC</td>
                <td colspan="2" rowspan="4">CAINOZOIC(NEOZOIC) Cz</td>
                <td colspan="3">Cuaternar Q</td>
                <td colspan="2" rowspan="3">Ciclul alpin</td>
                <td rowspan="15">0,01</td>
                <td colspan="4">Omul primitiv, mamut, ren, bou moscat, rinocer</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```